# how to fetch data from two table in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

this is action url

http://localhost/carsdirectory/cars/home

cars_controller.php(controller)

```
public function home(){

    $this->set('latest_cars', $this->Car->find('all', array(
        'order' => array(
            'Car.modified DESC',
            'Car.created Desc'              
        ),
        'limit' => '3'
     )));

    $this->set('galleries', $this->Gallery->find('all'));


 }
```

car.php(model)

```
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Gallery' => array(
        'className' => 'Gallery',
        'foreignKey' => 'car_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

gallery.php(model)

```
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Car' => array(
            'className' => 'Car',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_id',
)
   );
```

home.ctp(view)

```
<?php foreach($latest_cars as $latest_car){ ?>

  <img src="img/car-listings.jpg" />     // now it's static

     <h4><?php echo $latest_car['Car']['car_name']; ?></h4>  // it's dynamic it's coming car table 

     <span>$<?php echo $latest_car['Car']['car_price']; ?></span>  // it's dynamic it's coming car table 


<?php } ?>
```

i have replace that line

```
 <img src="img/car-listings.jpg" />
```

with that line

```
  <?php $this->Html->image('/media/filter/small/'.$latest_cars['Gallery']['dirname'].'/'.$latest_cars['Gallery']['basename']);?>
```

but i m getting that error

Undefined index: Gallery [APP\views\cars\home.ctp, line 226]

```
 <img src="img/car-listings.jpg" />  this line i want to make dynamic , so my question how to use join in cars_controller or any other idea and i want to fetch data from galleries table
```

this is galleries table structure

id     -            1

basename   -            chrysanthemum_10.jpg

car_id      -            1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a `Car` model and a `Gallery` model. Since `Gallery` has a `car_id` property, it can be used to form these CakePHP [Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together):

> Gallery belongsTo Car

and

> Car hasOne Gallery

You can choose which associations you actually need and define them in your models. In your case, you want to show the car's gallery when querying for cars, so:

```
// in car.php

var $hasOne = 'Gallery';
```

Then you can choose whether you want to use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1323/Containable) to control which associations get included in queries, or just use `recursive` to include all of them:

```
// in cars_controller.php

$this->set('latest_cars', $this->Car->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 1,
    'order' => array(
        'Car.modified DESC',
        'Car.created Desc'              
    ),
    'limit' => '3'
 )));
```

Then in your view, use `$latest_car['Car']` to access the car properties and `$latest_car['Gallery']` to access the gallery properties

**EDIT**

If a `Car` hasMany `Gallery`, then you should expect this structure:

```
[0] =>
    Car => (first car)
    Gallery =>
       [0] => (first gallery of first car)
       [1] => (second gallery of first car)
[1] => 
    Car => (second car)
    Gallery =>
       [0] => (first gallery of second car)

etc.
```

so to access it in your view:

```
<?php 
     foreach($latest_cars as $latest_car){ 
         foreach ($latest_car['Gallery'] as $gallery)
             echo $this->Html->image('/media/filter/small/'.$gallery['dirname'].'/'.$gallery['basename']);
?>
```

Comment: i have add in car.php public $hasMany = array(
     'Gallery' => array(
         'className' => 'Gallery',
         'foreignKey' => 'car_id',
         'dependent' => true
  )
 ); and gallery.php var $belongsTo = array(
   'Car' => array(
    'className' => 'Car',
    'foreignKey' => 'car_id',
 )
); but i m getting that msg Undefined index: Gallery [APP\views\cars\home.ctp, line 226] , could u help me more plz

Comment: did you use `recursive` or containable?

Comment: Mr ori , i dont no about recursive or containable , i m new in cake php, but i have edited my question , so plz u can check now

Comment: Mr ori , i need ur help, i want to count image(first gallery of first car) while display image, could u tell me plz how to do it?

Comment: sorry, I'm really busy these days and I don't understand what you want to do. Why don't you post a new question? There's enough people who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Use join in Controller find, specify fields as  required

```
$results= $this->Car->find('all',
array('fields'=> array('Car.*','galleries.*'), 
'joins'=> array( 
array('table'=>'galleries', 'type'=>'inner',
'conditions'=>array('Car.car_id=galleries.car_id'))
))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your controller file

```
  $this->loadModel('Table');//table is your model name in singular
  $this->set('table', $this->Table->find('all'));
```

you can use $table in view directly, and if you have relation with table you can use default relation provided by CakePHP

Thanks